# how to bind click event of div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="profile_ops" style="display:none">
  <button class="ybutton" id="viewclick" >View</button>&nbsp;
  <button class="ybutton" id="editclick" >Edit</button>&nbsp;
  <button class="ybutton" id="change_pswd" >Change Password</button>&nbsp;
  <button class="ybutton"  id="change_pic" >Change Picture</button>&nbsp;
</div>
```

in this i show this div on particular condition and i hide the view button but on edit click i show the view button but i want to give click event of view button where should i give the click event of div ?

i have tried giving the click event in edit click but it is giving me errro?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just assign the client event to each one

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  $("#viewclick").click( function() {
    // this will fire when you click view
  });
  $("#editclick").click( function() {
    // this will fire when you click edit
    // hide the view button here and upon submit, show it again
    // like $("#viewclick").hide() or $("#viewclick").fadeOut()
  });

});
```

Comment: I believe that `$('#element).on('click',function(e){ this.yatta(); });` is preferred method as of 5/2014

Comment: @b_dubb edit the answer if you think it's better. Look at the date when it was answered "Oct 2010"... I'm almost sure that `.on` was not an option by that time and only was started to use when we had differences attaching to created nodes (`live`), and BTW your `.on` is not correct, it should be `$(<node to attach the event, normally body or an ul>).on(<event>, <node to act as trigger>, <anonymous function or function name>);`

Answer (score 2):

You should put view button outside the div

```
<button class="ybutton" id="viewclick" onclick="ShowHide();">View</button>&nbsp; 
<div id="profile_ops" style="display:none"> 
                           <button class="ybutton" id="editclick" >Edit</button>&nbsp; 
                    <button class="ybutton" id="change_pswd" >Change Password</button>&nbsp; 
                    <button class="ybutton"  id="change_pic" >Change Picture</button>&nbsp; 
                </div>
```

when you click view button your div is show and view button is hide,
And when you click on edit button view button again getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Add the code on a `script` tag.

This can be done in different ways, first lets say your `script` tag comes before the element:

```
<script></script>
<div></div>
```

So you have to bind the click event only after the element is rendered, you can do this using:

```
$("div").live("click", function () {});
```

[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) will add an eventhandler on the window and check for the click event, then it checks the target, if it matches the event is triggered. This way, any element added at anytime on the DOM will trigger this handler.

Another way is using [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (`$(function(){})` is an alias). This function adds a function that will be executed when the page DOM loads.

```
$(function() {
    // when all elements have been loaded, add event on 'div'
    $("div").click(function () { });
});
```

If your script comes after your element

```
<div></div>
<script></script>
```

Then you can simply use `$("div").click`, unless the contents of the div are loaded dynamically.

**References**

- [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

you can bind the click event of view button from the start. Even if the event is binded. The user cannot fire the event if the button ins not seen / visible. so if the view is not visible the click event never fires. But when user clicks on edit the view will be visible and the event is already binded so will be able to click and the related click logic will fine.

Comment: You can fire the event with javascript.  You are right in that the user can't fire the event since they can't click the button on their own, but JS can click buttons that are not visible.

Comment: i answered question as it was asked. He was more View (visible) / Not viewed (invisible) centric in click binding context. I am aware of the javascript behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand much of what you said, but to add a hide/show event you could do something like this:

```
$('#editclick').toggle(function() {
  $('#viewclick').css('display', 'none');
}, function() {
  $('#viewclick').css('display', 'inline');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('#element).on( 'click',
   function(e){ 
      this.change(); 
  });
```

Comment: Can the #element be the id of a div?

Answer (score 0):

```
function ShowHide() {
    $("#profile_ops").show();
    $("#viewclick").hide();   
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#editclick").click(function(){
        $("#viewclick").show();

    });

})


    <button class="ybutton" id="viewclick"   onclick="ShowHide();">View</button>&nbsp; 
    <div id="profile_ops" style="display:none"> 
        <button class="ybutton" id="editclick" >Edit</button>&nbsp; 
        <button class="ybutton" id="change_pswd" >Change   Password</button>&nbsp; 
        <button class="ybutton"  id="change_pic" >Change Picture</button>&nbsp; 
    </div>
```